# Ошибки с виджетами в AndroidStudio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator

Изза этой ошибки все виджеты смещаются на координаты 0; 0;.[image: телефон]

также все виджеты прикреплены между особой.[image: ошибки]

activity main в текстовой версии

```
 package com.exemple.guessinggame;

 import android.os.Bundle;

 import com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton;
 import com.google.android.material.snackbar.Snackbar;

 import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
 import androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar;

 import android.widget.EditText;
 import android.widget.Button;
 import android.widget.TextView;

 import android.view.View;
 import android.view.Menu;
 import android.view.MenuItem;




public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private EditText txtGuess;
private Button btnGuess;
private TextView lblOutput;



private int theNumber;

public void newGame()
{
    theNumber = (int)(Math.random() * 10);
}


public void checkGuess()
{




    String guessText = lblOutput.getText().toString();
    int guess = Integer.parseInt(guessText);
    String message = "";

    try
    {

        if ( guess > theNumber )
        {
            message = guess + " is to high, try again ";
        }

        else if ( guess < theNumber )
        {
            message = guess + " is too low, try again ";
        }

        else
        {
            message = guess + " is true, u Win ";
            newGame();
        }
    }

    catch (Exception e)
    {
        message = " is shiet ";
    }

    finally
    {
      lblOutput.setText(message);
      txtGuess.requestFocus();
      txtGuess.selectAll();

    }
}
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    txtGuess = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtGuess);
    btnGuess = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnGuess);
    lblOutput = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.lblOutput);
    newGame();

    btnGuess.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            checkGuess();
        }
    });

    Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    FloatingActionButton fab = findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .setAction("Action", null).show();
        }
    });
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
   }
  }
```

а также content main в текстовой версии

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="56dp"
    android:text="It Is Goha's Program"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/lblOutput"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/lblOutput"
    android:layout_width="224dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="42dp"
    android:text="Enter a number between 1 and 10"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/txtGuess"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnGuess"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="28dp"
    android:text="Button"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/txtGuess"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/txtGuess" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/txtGuess"
    android:layout_width="90dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="135dp"
    android:autofillHints=""
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="number"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/textView3"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/textView3"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.888"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/lblOutput" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="336dp"
    android:text="And press on button"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/txtGuess" />

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

При открытии эмулятора, вылазят такие ошибки :

[image: ошибки]

и вот такие :

[image: во]

И еще раз, проблема заключается в том, что хотя виджеты прикреплены по вертикали и горизонтали, они все ровно смещаются на исходную позицию.

Извините за мою непрофессиональность)

Comment: Вот это `app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"` у Вас зачем в разметке? Вряд ли проблема из-за этого, но других проблем я вообще не вижу. И еще вопросик, какое название xml файла, который Вы прикрепили?

Comment: как это, в разметке?

Comment: разметка = .xml файл

Comment: ну без него вообще ничего не пашет, а название content_main

Comment: заработало! Спасибо)

Comment: отметьте ответ правильным, пожалуйста.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У Вас в коде используется файл разметки activity_main.xml `setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);`.

А в вопросе Вы приложили файл content_main.xml. И именно его, как я понял, Вы редактируете. Вызывайте его из кода и все заработает!